# Export grouped shape as image

Tags: excel, vba, jpeg, shapes

I need to export grouped shapes named 'center' to a share folder as .jpg.

I have code that does the job if using keyboard button f8.
If code runs as normal it exports a blank picture.

```vb
Sub Export_JPG()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Worksheets("KPI")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Worksheets("ChartPage")

Dim chtObj As ChartObject
Dim SharepointAddress As String
Dim myshape As shape

ws1.Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()"

Set myshape = ws1.Shapes("center")
Set chtObj = ws2.ChartObjects.Add(myshape.Left, myshape.Top, myshape.Width, myshape.Height)

myshape.CopyPicture
chtObj.Chart.Paste

SharepointAddress = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\1.jpg"
Kill SharepointAddress
chtObj.Chart.Export Filename:=SharepointAddress, Filtername:="JPG"

chtObj.Delete
Set chtObj = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Does a `DoEvents` after `chtObj.Chart.Paste` help? Or even a `chtObj.Select`? To me that looks like the chart is not ready with rendering before you export. That is why it works using F8 (here there is enough time between paste and export).

Comment: What type is your `"center"` shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please insert a line between `CopyPicture` and `Paste`:

```
myshape.CopyPicture
 chtObj.Select
chtObj.Chart.Paste 'it works only for a selected chart!
```

Comment: chtObj.Select helped. Thanks!